# How to debug a third-party Gradle plugin?

Tags: java, android, debugging, gradle

I'm trying to sign an Android AAR artifact using the [gradle signing plugin](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/signing_plugin.html). Unfortunately, I'm getting a rather unhelpful `NullPointerException` in the process:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':library:signArchives'.
> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':library:signArchives'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
        [...snip...]
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:32)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:33)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:130)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPSignatureGenerator.initSign(Unknown Source)
        at org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPSignatureGenerator.initSign(Unknown Source)
        at org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPSignatureGenerator$initSign.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.plugins.signing.signatory.pgp.PgpSignatory.createSignatureGenerator(PgpSignatory.groovy:54)
        at org.gradle.plugins.signing.signatory.pgp.PgpSignatory.sign(PgpSignatory.groovy:64)
        [...snip...]
        ... 52 more


BUILD FAILED
```

What's the easiest way to debug this exception? Is there a way to attach a debugger to gradle? Can I build the signing plugin, insert some logging statements and tell my build to pick up my custom version instead of the one it ships with?

Comment: Did you provide a pgp key file?

Comment: Yes, and it seems to pick up a key. Changing the keyId to an invalid one leads to an actual error message.

Comment: Judging from the source code of PGPSignatureGenerator and PgpSignatory and from the error message you gave, sign-plugin gets null private key. Please, ensure that you created a valid signing key with a command like "gpg --gen-key" and passed it in android/signingConfigs configuration.

Comment: When you invoke gpg, it typically shows you a menu with a choice of key type. Choose that type with "signing" word in it.

Comment: It's the right key. I can manually sign using the idea with `gpg --sign` and verify it. It also worked using the signing plugin for maven.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to a [thread in the gradle forums](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/how_do_you_attach_a_debugger_to_gradle_so_that_i_can_debug_it_running_a_task) there is a somewhat secret `org.gradle.debug`-flag that allows you to attach a debugger.

```
gradle someTask --no-daemon -Dorg.gradle.debug=true
```

For the hotfixing/custom-plugin it should be enough to put your copied & modified plugin in `rootProjectDir/buildSrc/src/main/groovy`. You can read more about writing a custom plugin on the [Gradle site](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html).

Comment: Thanks, Marcel! Being a Java/JVM noob, I couldn't figure out how to attach the debugger after setting the flag, but the `buildSrc` hint was really helpful. After copying over the latest version of the plugin from Gradle git and changing its name to a unique identifier (it doesn't shadow the built-in plugins), it turned out that my crash was already fixed in master.

Answer (score 4):

This is how I did it using IntelliJ - Android Studio is based on IntelliJ so it should be the same, and other IDEs should be similar:

Download the correct version of the source code of the buggy Gradle plugin, or clone/access its version control repository and check out the relevant branch or tag corresponding to the version of the buggy Gradle plugin you are using. Import the code into IntelliJ by using File -> New project from existing sources. Then run, at the command line:

```
./gradlew someTask -Dorg.gradle.debug=true --no-daemon
```

and create a new remote debugging connection using port 5005, set your initial breakpoint, and start it.

Alternatively, you can use the Gradle daemon by instead doing `./gradlew -Dorg.gradle.jvmargs="`*standard JVM debugging arguments*`"`, and this way you can use any debugging port you like, but I have not tested this. For example:

```
./gradlew \
  -Dorg.gradle.jvmargs="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=5005,suspend=y" \
  someTask
```